# Реакция Visual Studio на ICompileModule

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

В ASP.NET 5 проектах есть возможность программно влиять на ход компиляции (мета-программирование) [описание и пример](http://www.inversionofcontrol.co.uk/meta-programming-with-roslyn-on-aspnet-vnext/).

В данном случае тело метода `GetMessage` класса `Greeter` заменяется на `return "\"Hello World!\""`;

Да, компиляция проходит без ошибок, однако, во время редактирования кода студия указывает на код как на ошибочный.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как "научить" студию анализировать код с учетом модулей к компилятору?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду ошибку компилятора или Intellisense?

Comment: @VladD, и то и другое

Comment: Ну. Intellisense имеет право тупить, а компилятор-то хоть понимает?

Comment: студия все нормально анализирует, а вам неплохо бы вернуть хотя бы `null`, что бы несмущать самого себя

Comment: @VladD, компилируется все корректно

Comment: @Dmitry, в данном случае я привел просто пример. Реальная же задача не просто "заменить тело функции", меня интересуют более сложные задачи (например, сделать поддержку generic аттрибутов и аргументов типа Expression в конструкторе аттритуба). Так что, меня интересует именно **как подружить Visual Studio с ICompileModule**

Comment: @maxswitcher: Окей, в качестве эксперимента: если вы на время отключите Intellisense, то всё будет в порядке? Так мы ограничим проблему.

Comment: @VladD, отключение Intellisense нежелательно, ибо именно из за него Visual Studio так хороша.

Comment: @maxswitcher: Я же пишу: **временно**, для локализации проблемы. Временно можно?

Comment: @maxswitcher давайте рассуждать логически, откуда редактор кода должен знать заранее, как вы хотите повлиять на компиляцию? это же не совсем родное типа `#if DEBUG`

Comment: @VladD, не имеет смысла.

Comment: @maxswitcher: Ну вот представьте, в вашей программе 20 функций, и она работает неправильно. Вам советуют временно выкинуть половину, чтобы понять, где неправильно работающая функция, и вы им отвечаете, что не хотите, потому что программа в конце-концов будет работать с ними всеми. Вы сами себе не хотите помочь.

Comment: @Dmitry, как я понял, 2015 студия для ASP.NET 5 проектов анализирует код через DNX, потому я и думаю, что есть возможность "научить" студию понимать плагины компилятора.

Comment: @maxswitcher думаю да, решарпер же может, но опять же, надо смотреть как это все работает

Comment: @VladD, тут ситуация совершенно иная. Программа (Visual Studio) в данном случае работает корректно (поскольку она не читает модули компилятора, ибо не должна) и отключение Intellisense для того, чтобы не видеть "ошибку" абсолютно никак не поможет понять, как "научить Visual Studio читать модули компилятора".